# AutoIT for Python Script

Tags: python, autoit

I am preparing a small script to automatize a process in my laptop. In order to do that I have to maximize the window open with autoit. Here I attached the code. I received an error with the @SW_SHOWMAXIMIZE.

```
import pyautogui as py
import autoit as it
import time

py.FAILSAFE = False

# Abrimos la aplicación
it.run(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Optris GmbH\PIX Connect\Imager.exe', work_dir = "", show_flag=@SW_SHOWMAXIMIZE)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you edit your post to add the error stacktrace ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not Showmaximize, its swmaximize check here in docs https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Run.htm

```
show_flag=@SW_MAXIMIZE
```

Comment: `Constants are defined in AutoItConstants.au3.`. If the flag `@SW_MAXIMIZE ` doesn't work, try it's value (`@SW_MAXIMIZE` = `3`).